# Minimum distance to reach till end

Tags: algorithm

Please help me with the below problem statement:

> Bounce is a fast bunny. This time she faces the challenging task of completing all the trades on a number line.
> Initially, bounce is at the 0th position, and the trades to be performed are on the right side(position>0).
>
> She has two list of equal length, one containing the value v[i], and the other position p[i], for each of the trade it needs to perform .
>
> The given list 'pos' is in strictly increasing order, that is pos[i]<pos[i+1], for 1<=i<=n-1 (1 based indexing) where n is the sizeof list.
> the trade values can be positive, negative or zero.
>
> During the process she cannot have a resource count of strictly less than zero at any moment, and after finishing all the trades she should finish at the right most position of trade(even if trade value is zero).
> It is guaranteed that the sum of all trades is greater than or equal to zero.
>
> Bounce can jump from any position to any other position. If she jumps from pos1 to pos2, the distance covered is |pos1-pos2|, and the distance for this jump is added to total distance covered.
>
> find the Total minimum total Bounce has to cover to complete all the trades and then end at the last(rightmost) position of the trade.

Constraints

```
1<=n<=10^5
-1000<=v[i]<=1000
1<=pos<=10^8
```

Sample I/O: 1

```
4
2
-3
1
2
1
2
3
4

6
```

Explanation:

```
Number of trades = 4v = {2,-3,1,2}
position = {1,2,3,4}

at x=1
we gain 2 resources and resource count is 2
at x=2
we can't trade as we have only 2 resources
at x=3
we gain 1 more resource and count becomes 3(now go back to 2 and finish pending task and come back)
distance covered = 3+1+1 = 5
at x=4
we gain 2 more resource and exit

Hence, total distance covered = 6
```

Sample I/O: 2

```
4
2
-3
-1
2
1
2
3
4

8
```

I was asked this question in an interview and wasn't able to answer and i'm unable to solve it till now. I tried to relate this with many concepts like DAG, maximum sum, Kadane's Algo. but none was helpful.

How to approach this question and how to relate this with any existing algorithm?

It is an past interview question for which i don't have any link. I just want to know what i could have done at that time which would had solved it.

Comment: In your example, the covered distance should be 5: Go from pos1 to pos3 (2) + from pos3 to pos2 (1) + from pos2 to pos4 (2) = 5.

Comment: what about the distance from starting position to posiition1 ?

you missed that

Comment: OK. So it should be 1 (from 0 to 1) + 2 + 1 + 2 = 6 (not 3 + 1 + 1 + 1). Right?

Comment: 0->1->2->3->2->3->4  or 0->1->2->3->2->4  => 6 distance covered

Comment: Ideally you should move sequentially, but if there's no negative values in-between you may jump all the steps at once and add all the resource values in total resource count and distance between position in total distance count

Comment: Now, it's clear.

Comment: Thanks... Kindly help if you figure something out

Comment: Your Sample I/O number 2 is in contradiction with the problem description: *" It is guaranteed that the sum of all trades is greater than or equal to zero."* Can you clarify or correct?

Comment: Thanks @trincot for pointing. I have corrected the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A greedy algorithm works here: as you walk forward, and would get a negative accumulated result, then you know that you'll have to get back to this position some time later. This means that every next step counts three times (forward, backward and forward again). As you know that the conflicting negative trade amount will eventually need to be accumulated, you might as well account for it immediately, knowing that you will have to triple the distance of the following steps until you have a positive accumulated amount.

So here is how that algorithm can be implemented in JavaScript. The two examples are run:

```js
function minDistance(v, p) {
    let distance = 0;
    let position = 0;
    let resources = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        let step = p[i] - position;
        if (resources < 0) distance += step * 3; // need to get back & forth here
        else distance += step;
        resources += v[i]; // all trades have to be performed anyway
        position = p[i];
    }
    return distance;
}

console.log(minDistance([2,-3,1,2], [1,2,3,4])); // 6

console.log(minDistance([2,-3,-1,2], [1,2,3,4])); // 8
```

Comment: Can you please explain the sequence corresponding with the result 4 that your code seems to provide for `minDistance([2, 100, -100, -100],  [1,2,3,4])` ?

Comment: Not a valid input input. If you collect all the inputs through the end you will end up with a positive value in contrast to your case where everything sums up to be negative.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I did not regard that as a valid input. I think we are supposed to assume the overall sum is non-negative, since the instructions are *"...to complete all the trades and then end at the last(rightmost) position of the trade"*.

Comment: @Anand and trincot, how is this sum non-negative? 2,-3,-2,1

Comment: Indeed, that is a problem with the example that the OP gave, because it it is in contradiction with the OP's statement *"It is guaranteed that the sum of all trades is greater than or equal to zero."*

Comment: Hi @גלעדברקן  trincot, I'm really sorry guys for misunderstanding. i have corrected the sample input. It was 2,-3, -1, 2 and not 2, -3,  -2, 1. Please help

Comment: My apologies for the late response. please reconsider and help. I'm afraid that the greedy approach might not work as we are not keeping track of individual negative values and there position. I'm not sure whether that's required but i think those should be tracked to develope some optimal solution.

Comment: @Anand if you do not believe this solution is optimal in all cases, please offer either a proof or a simple counterexample.

Comment: I don't see what I should reconsider? I stand by this solution. Do you have a problem with a certain input?

Comment: I tried some sample test cases of my own and unable to get any invalid output. The reason why i was asking to reconsider as i was thinking if the negative resource order may had some significance of some sort which later can be used to some optimization like in dp. But, after trying with 2-3 sample cases of my own this may be the correct approach. Thanks @trincot for help and apologies for delay in earlier response.